# Unstable query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stability, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am using SQL Server 2008-R2 Express Edition.

I wrote the query shown below to generate number sequences from 1 to @n. In testing it (purely in a query window), I found that if I significantly change the value of @n, I get incorrect results. Re-execution yields the same errors. However, if I open a new query window, the results are perfect.

Looking at the algorithm, it makes no sense to me as to why I should be getting unstable results (or even that a query can produce varying results against a fixed input).

```
DECLARE @n INT;

SET @n = 65536;

DECLARE @t TABLE (n INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

IF @n > 0 BEGIN
    DECLARE @r INT, @i INT, @l INT;

    SET @r = FLOOR(1.442695040888964 * LOG(@n));
    SET @i = 1;
    SET @l = 0;

    INSERT INTO @t (n) VALUES (1);

    WHILE @l < @r BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @t (n) SELECT n + @i FROM @t;

        SET @i = @i * 2;
        SET @l = @l + 1;
    END;

    INSERT INTO @t (n) SELECT TOP (@n - @i) n + @i FROM @t;
END;

--SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @t;

select * from @t
```

**EDIT**

Change the 65536 to 5000, execute, change back to 65536, and scroll down to say row 169,770. I get row 169770 = 40000. In a new window, it runs correctly.

**EDIT2**

Besides getting randomly correct/incorrect results, it appears something else is wrong. I now am getting consistently incorrect results for some numbers such as 655360.

Comment: What are you trying to actually do? There are many Number tables solutions out there? What values does it fail for?

Comment: @gbn this started as a code golf exercise to create a number sequence. It works perfectly, unless I change @n dramatically. But, like I said, I can copy & paste the query to a new window, and I'll get 100% correct results. So it seems to me there is a bug that is not in my query.

Comment: It works perfectly for me because you haven't given any example numbers that fail. What I don't get is the use of LOG and FLOOR for a Tally table

Comment: @gbn change the 65536 to 655360 and scroll down to say row 160,000. I get row 169770 = 40000. In a new window, it runs correctly.

Comment: @gbn the LOG & FLOOR is simply the formula for @R = TRUNC(LOG_2(@N))

Comment: I use the log to work out the maximum number of times I can run the table doubling add. The balance is performed by the final insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an ORDER BY to the last statement.

There is no natural or default order in any table

Edit:

I attribute it the use of floating point numbers

I posted how to do a tally table an hour ago: [Maximum recursion has been exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209273/maximum-recursion-has-been-exhausted/5209342#5209342)

Comment: I tried putting an ORDER BY to the first select and temp. remarked out the last one. It didn't help. For @n = 655360, I get the following: row 4354 => n = 4354; row 4355 => n = 133731. Makes no sense.

Comment: I even tried this, to no avail:   INSERT INTO @t (n) SELECT t.n + @i FROM 
   (
    SELECT  TOP (100) PERCENT n
    FROM  @t
    ORDER BY n
   ) AS t;

Comment: @gbn oh, you mean to the final select. Got you.

Comment: @gbn I got it working 100%, thanks. It's several times faster than using recursion, too. Without digging more, I'm not clear on how to use your tally code to simply generate an ordered sequence.

Comment: @gbn ok I figured it out. Yours is faster too ;) How the heck did you figure that code out?

Comment: @gbn I get how your tally code works. Smart. I wanted to go that route but didn't know how. What I don't understand is your format, specifically your use of WITH. There is no CTE name or AS. The final query part just flows on, as if a CTE doesn't exist. What use of WITH is this?

Comment: There are 7 CTEs (Pass0 to Tally) and the main query starts "SELECT TOP 1"